# NSLayoutAttribute change position of image from left to righ

Tags: swift, uiimageview, storyboard

How can I change the position of an image using storyboard and constrains from left to right using NSLayoutAttribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it using 2 IBOutlet of NSLayoutConstraint for leading and trailing and change the constant for them